# No intellisense ("no definition found") for local JS dependencies even though they are fully typed

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, types, intellisense

**Problem:** When importing from `node_modules` in `mycode.js`, some modules are fully typed and intellisense is available, while others don't get that luxury.

E.g., when I press F12 with cursor on any file in `src`, it works.

E.g., when I press F12 with cursor on `'lodash/minBy'`, it also takes me to the correct type definition file (which is in a global `node_modules` folder for some reason, even though, I have it installed locally).

But when I press F12 with cursor on `'sigma'`, it complains "No definition found", as illustrated in this screenshot: [image]

Naturally, lodash has full typing and intellisense support, while `Sigma` does not.

I already changed my `jsconfig.json`'s `include` settings like so, but it did not help:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "esnext",
    "checkJs": false,  /* Typecheck .js files. */
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "src/**/*",
    "../node_modules/sigma",
    "../node_modules/sigma/**/*",
    "../node_modules/graphology",
    "../node_modules/graphology/**/*"
  ]
}
```

The project is a mono-repo. My paths are:

```
root/some-package/jsconfig.json
root/some-package/src/mycode.js
root/node_modules/{sigma,graphology,etc.}
```

Comment: Have you tried install the types,  `npm install @types/sigmajs`

Comment: @Keith `sigmajs` is entirely different from `sigma`. `sigma` has its types bundled (you can see them in `node_modules/sigma`. But maybe they are not linked up correctly? Not sure.